# How to fetch data from another excel in current Excel in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, lookup, ssis-2012

I am currently bringing data into from excel file as a source and after very basic ETL operations, bringing the final data into Excel Destination. The excel destination file contains a column "Inventory_Min_Stock" that needs to bring data from another excel file into it. I know this is possible by LOOKUP in SSIS but not sure how to bring data in LOOKUP?

See below image of my SSIS Package:

[image]

The left side brings the data from Source to Destination Excel.

The end result of the excel looks something as seen below. I am looking to fill Min_Stock based on Item_ID and Locaton_ID. The Min_Stock-ItemID and locationID have values to be filled from another excel file.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it's possible to use Excel as the source of a Lookup.  I would try to solve this with a Merge Join instead.

Comment: How would you do that with Merge Join? Care to explain or give an example?!

Comment: I don't think the internet needs another merge join tutorial.   Try one of these:   https://www.google.com/search?q=ssis+merge+join&oq=ssis+merge+join&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2319j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8    Do the join on Item_ID & Location_ID.

Comment: How about loading the data into a staging table then doing the lookup? is that possible?

Comment: @speedinfusion yes, that is possible, but I assumed from the question that the poster wanted to solve this without creating an additional table.